# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stanford-nlp

I am working with Stanford Parser API. My system specifications are listed below:

OS: Win8

IDE: .IntelliJIdea14

JDK: 1.8

Stanford-Parser 3.5.2 Version

I have imported stanford-parser.jar and ejml-0.23.jar in module dependencies (ClassPath). 
 There are some parser models that are saved in a jar file named stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.

The Stanford support team says:

> "In recent distributions, the models are included in a jar file inside
>   the parser distribution. For example, in the 2012-11-12 distribution,
>   the models are included in stanford-parser-2.0.4-models.jar The
>   easiest way to access these models is to include this file in your
>   classpath. The parser will then be able to read the models from that
>   jar file. "

But I can't import  stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar file. So I extracted it, save the model in an appropriate address in D Drive and finally changed the following code:

```
String parserModel = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz";

LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parserModel);
```

**To**

```
String parserModel = "D:\\ MasterofScience\\Tools\\Stanford Dependenct Tree\\models" +
    "\\lexparser\\englishPCFG.ser.gz";

 LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(parserModel);
```

But I give these exception errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 6 more
```

Even I Don’t change the code, I receive the same exception!
What should I do?

Comment: The program is looking for a class in a folder that doesn't exist: `edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the parser jar (`stanford-parser.jar`) in your classpath. Really, you can add both the parser jar and the model jar to your classpath, and then the program should work.

Comment: I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
 how can i solve it ?